# What does it mean to return different value for each position in RecyclerView adapter getItemViewType()?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter, android-viewholder

As the title says, If I Override `getItemViewType(int position)` in the adapter of a RecyclerView:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

Does that mean I won't have views **recycled**? Since it means I have a different type of view in each position?

If so, is this equivalent to `setIsRecyclable(true)` ?

I'm asking this because I faced a problem with RecyclerView items mixed and duplicated in endless scrolling. Tried `getItemViewId()` to return a unique Id but didn't work. The only two ways it worked is by `setIsRecyclable(true)` and returning different value for each position from `getItemViewType(position)`

Comment: There is an underlying issue that you are somehow making work with these calls. If you need some assistance to getting to the bottom of it,  I suggest that you post another question (if you haven't already) that addresses the items that are "mixed and duplicated."

Answer (score 0):

`getItemViewType()` tells the `RecyclerView` what kind of view is at the position. See the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#getItemViewType(int)).

> **getItemViewType**
>
> Return the view type of the item at position for the purposes of view recycling.
>
> The default implementation of this method returns 0, making the assumption of a single view type for the adapter. Unlike ListView adapters, types need not be contiguous. Consider using id resources to uniquely identify item view types.
>
> ...
>
> Returns int    integer value identifying the type of the view needed to represent the item at position. Type codes need not be contiguous.

Your code won't prevent views from being recycled. I do not think that you want to return the position since that indicates that you have a different type of view for every position.

Comment: I had to use this, since I had a problem with mixed and duplicateed recyclerview items, tried `getItemViewId()` but nothing fixed, only this and `setIsRecyclable(true)` fixed it.